# Collecting metrics using Apache's Stopwatch, clarification needed

Tags: java, performance, stopwatch

Please consider the following snippet:

```
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start();

    Thread.sleep(1000);  //< ---- event 1

    stopWatch.split();

    Thread.sleep(2000);  //< ---- event 2

    stopWatch.split();

    Thread.sleep(3000);  //< ---- event 3

    System.out.println(stopWatch.getStartTime());
    System.out.println(stopWatch.getSplitTime());
    System.out.println(stopWatch.toString());
    System.out.println(stopWatch.toSplitString());
```

It seems that using `StopWatch` I can break down a single event into many sub-events, but even so, how can i collect this information? For example, looking at above code, is it possible to recognize that thee were 3 events with first one taking 1 second, second one taking 2 seconds and 3rd one taking 3 seconds?

Please let me know.

If Stopwatch is not a way to go, is there an existing library i can use for something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getSplitTime() method returns the latest split time. You should call it after the relevant split.

However, I would measure every event with a new stopWatch (preferably in a single dedicated method), so that you don't have do subtract time durations to get the time per event.

Comment: Right. That's what i ended up doing. Thought may be i am missing something simple